# How do I word break column in a table

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to word-break a column in a table but it doesn't seem to work when I include CSS width and word-wrap. Here is what I have done so far:

```
 <div className="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                        <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><strong>Category</strong></th>
                                    <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                                    <th style={{ width: "30%" }}><strong>Description</strong></th>
                                    <th><strong>Country</strong></th>
                                    <th><strong>Date</strong></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {prodData.map(record => {
                                    return (<React.Fragment>
                                        <tr key={record._id}>
                                            <td>{record.category}</td>
                                            <td>{record.name}</td>
                                            <td style={{width: "200px",wordWrap:"break-word"}}>{record.description}</td>
                                            <td>{record.country}</td>
                                            <td>{(moment(record.date).format('YYYY/MM/DD'))}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                    )
                                }
                                )}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the screenshot of the table:

[image]

How do I word-break on the description column? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any hepls. Thanks again

Comment: Usually having a `p` tag should create a paraph which breaks the text down. But maybe also check your style so that you are sure that container has actually a width size.

Comment: Add this css ---> `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-worker-kv7z7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am post it as answer, it might help someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below style,

**style={{ wordBreak: "break-word" }}**

```
<React.Fragment>
                    <tr key={record._id}>
                      <td>{record.category}</td>
                      <td>{record.name}</td>
                      <td
                        style={{ width: "200px", wordBreak: "break-word" }}
                      >
                        {record.description}
                      </td>
                      <td>{record.country}</td>
                      <td>Test</td>
                    </tr>
                  </React.Fragment>
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-worker-kv7z7?file=/src/App.js:1884-2434

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px; //give your size
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```